# Poor quality of resized UIImages

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage, retina-display

I am trying to create an application compatible with both retina and non-retina displays. I am using high resolution images and letting the OS scale them down for the non-retina displays.

The images are named xxx@2x.png and I load with the same name. This works, and the images are displayed at the same relative size on both device types. Unfortunately, the quality of the resized image on the non-retina display is far from ideal.

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.image = [localAssets imageAtPath:@"content/home/settings@2x.png"];

+ (UIImage*)imageAtPath:(NSString*)path;
{
    NSString* extension = [path pathExtension];
    path = [path stringByDeletingPathExtension];

    NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[path lastPathComponent] 
                                                         ofType:extension 
                                                    inDirectory:[path stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]];
    UIImage* theImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    if(!theImage)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error no file found at %@", [path stringByAppendingPathExtension:extension]);
    }
    return theImage;
}
```

Retina:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/gmn1q.png]

Legacy:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your resize your images yourself, and save them as xxx.png and xxx@2x.png, then you can use them as "xxx" and iOS will automatically use the @2x versions when using a Retina display.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to avoid wasting the extra disk space. It just seemed like I was missing something in the UIImage call that was causing it to look so bad after being resized.

Comment: Since you're already storing the retina-size images with your app, it seems like having non-retina ones wouldn't take all that much additional space... But of course I don't know the details of your project.

Comment: 25% more disk space is nothing to sneeze at if it's the 25% that pushes you over 50MB.

Comment: That's a fair point. See if you can optimize your images a little more, for example by using `UIImage imageNamed:resizableImageWithCapInsets`, where appropriate.